# How to convert a single list into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a single list in Python like this:

```
my_list = ['name', 'degree', 'age', 'score']
```

and would like to convert it into a dictionary that should look like this, where
keys and value are taken from `my_list`

```
my_dict = {'name': name, 'degree': degree, 'age' : age, 'score': score}
```

I found a lot of examples how to convert lists, especially two lists into a dictionary, but nothing for my case.

Comment: Where do you want to get the values from?

Comment: You didn't find any readymade code, but did you try to write code yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension that looks up the variable names in `globals()`

```
my_dict = {var: globals()[var] for var in my_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary comprehension would probably be the easiest approach:

```py
my_dict = {i:i for i in my_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use zip with the dictionary constructor:

```
dict(zip(my_list,my_list))

{'name': 'name', 'degree': 'degree', 'age': 'age', 'score': 'score'}
```